# Quickly getting a slice of digits from a float

Tags: python, floating-point

Suppose I could look at a float as if it was some sort of a dict, in which the the keys range from -infinity to infinity, and the values are the digits in these places. That is, f[i] will return the integer which is closest to `(f % 10**(i+1) - f % 10**i) / 10**i`.

For example, if `f=1234.5678`, `f[-1] == 5` and `f[2] == 2`.

Furthermore: imagine the float would also support some weird form of image slicing (even though it is not a list, just like it is not a dict), so in our example `f[-1:2] == 345`.

I need this for practical reasons, and I need it to be done quickly. I guess I can write some clumsy stuff based on the expression I wrote in the first paragraph (which returns a float, with all of the problems of floats, which I should carefully convert to an integer).

So I wondered whether there's some simpler, or at least more elegant, **quick** solution (performance is an issue here), which does not involve libraries such as `decimal`.

It might worth mentioning that I am not looking after a solution which emulates the `__getitem__` or the slice notation. A function `def getslice(f, a, b)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Your formula sounds like you got most of the work done already. There are no 'quick' solutions here, as floats are not represented as digits, unless you format them as strings first.

Comment: I guess some clever string processing may do the work, but I have no ideas about the costs of casting back and fourth, and I am not sure string solutions could be really quicker.

Comment: Also, how'd you handle floats with exponents? Is the index relative to the decimal point always or to the floated point? E.g., what would index -1 of `1.5e-10` return?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it will return 0. Isn't that clear according to my attempt in the first paragraph?

Comment: Not necessarily; it wasn't clear if you had considered such numbers.

Comment: Do you have any hint of how to make the result of my formula above an `int`? Is `int(round(...))` the best solution?

Comment: Use the `timeit` module to find out what is faster, if time is critical, if that's the criteria for 'best solution'.

Comment: A **major** problem with this is that there is no floating-point number with value 1234.5678 in most Python implementations. Floating-point is usually represented with a binary base. The closest value to 1234.5678 is 1234.567800000000033833202905952930450439453125. That happens to have “678” as your example “substring” `f[-1:2]`, but what about 1234.5674? Attempting to assign `f = 1234.5674` actually results in 1234.5673999999999068677425384521484375, and then `f[-1:2]` is “673”, not “674”. How do you want to handle these situations?

Comment: I note your answer indicates that `f[i]` should produce the integer closest to `(f % 10**(i+1) - f % 10**i) / 10**i`. However, that does not solve or avoid the problem; it just means the rounding problem occurs in a different place (determining whether remaining value below the desired digit is greater than or less than .5 of the desired digit).

Comment: In my python implementation I see `1234.5678`. However, you are right, that's indeed a problem. It's one of the reasons of my question. Anyway, the expected output should have been the "natural" solution - 674. (you probably meant `f[-4:-1]`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "practical reasons"?  This seems like an odd thing to ask for, and there may be alternative way of solving your real problem, whatever that happens to be.

Comment: Getting a stream of floats, I wish to print a slice of their digits, as described, where the slice is determined according to some calculation done somewhere else. It has to be done quickly, as I may get quite a lot of floats.

Comment: Sure, I understand that.  The question is *why* you want to do this.  What's the application?  What's the use case?  If we understood where the question is coming from, we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: The floats represent prices. The prices may have high precisions, but are in some occasions very similar to one another. I wish to present only the digits in which there's change, but not all of them, and this is usually quite determined for a given product. I think that with some rounding assumptions I can get satisfying results using strings.

Answer (score 2):

you could  change it to string.

```
mystr = str(num)
```

then by having the position of '.' in `mystr`:

```
mystr[pos+index]
```

is what you need, where index is your way of defining the position before and after the floating point.

Comment: And what if there's no `.`? And what about floats with exponents?

Comment: by using 'find' you can find the position of '.' and know if it does have floating point or not.
if it does not have pos=0 will do the job.
for exponent you could use

format(num, '.xf') #x is max number of digits after floating point

before turning it to string

Comment: @user3310151: To ensure that you always get all digits, `format(num, '.1074f')` works.  I'm still not sure why one would want this, though.