# Getting a slice of a float from an irrational number

Tags: python, slice, precision, floating-accuracy, eulers-number

I am trying to find a way to slice an arbitrary index of an irrational number, eg. getting a slice of 5 digits of the Euler's number starting at the decimal index 100. This is not a practical task, just a thing I was wondering about.

[I was trying to find an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908605/quickly-getting-a-slice-of-digits-from-a-float)

and sliced my number after converting my float into string:

```
z=str(format(math.e, '.105f'))[-6:-1]
```

It does work with floats with smaller precision (till around .50f), but with bigger it returns zeros. I was wondering how could I possibly represent and slice long floats.

Comment: A number is a number, not a sequence of decimal digits and a period. Slicing or indexing a number does not make sense. Also, floats have limited precision. `math.e` represents the best possible `float` approximation of e, not the actual value.

Comment: `math`.e is 2.718281828459045, with 15 decimals digits, so there's no way you can find any digit of e further than that this way - even the last digit is only correct by chance, as the next digit is a 2, so it got rounded down.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a package [bigfloat](https://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/) for this very high precision arithmetics.